# Javascript array only holds most recent object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have the following code

```
followDB.find({user: username}, function(err, docs){
    if(err){console.log(err)}else {
      for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        postsDB.find({ user: docs[i].follow }, function (err, docs) {
            if(err){console.log(err)}
            else{
                for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                  var array = []
                var post = {
                  user: docs[i].user,
                  text: docs[i].text,
                  time: docs[i].time,
                  likes: docs[i].like,
                  id: docs[i]._id
                }
                array.push(post)
                console.log(array.length);
                  //socket.emit('Order Posts', user, text, time, likes, id)
                }
            }
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

For some reason array.length always equals one and I have no idea why. The object inside the array is always the last one submitted.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: You should never use the same index variable for the inner loop as you do for the outer loop. Can you see why?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan: I think he's OK what comes to that since the variables are in different functions and therefore distinct. It's still a good idea to rename at least one of them, just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan technically it's not "inner"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're recreating the array on every iteration.

Initialize it outside the for loop, before it, not inside it.

Comment: Holy moly how did i not think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the array outside the for loop

```
followDB.find({user: username}, function(err, docs){
        if(err){console.log(err)}else {
          for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
            postsDB.find({ user: docs[i].follow }, function (err, docs) {
                if(err){console.log(err)}
                else{
                    //simply change the array outside the for loop
                    var array = []
                    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {

                    var post = {
                      user: docs[i].user,
                      text: docs[i].text,
                      time: docs[i].time,
                      likes: docs[i].like,
                      id: docs[i]._id
                    }
                    array.push(post)
                    console.log(array.length);
                      //socket.emit('Order Posts', user, text, time, likes, id)
                    }
                }
            });
          }
        }
      })
```